# There is a way how to print on any bluetooth printer Device using Ipad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, bluetooth, ios6

I need to print a simple data structure in a portable bluetooth printer devices using a IOS apps.

Comment: sorry for previous answer, but the Bluetooth API it is private API so i think u can't use it. but u can do it in easy way like Daij-Djan give u an link to show or the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409385/printing-from-the-iphone-application

Answer (score 0):

on ios printing to an arbitary printer isnt possible for apps.
you need to use the UIPrintInteractionController AFAIK

see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/Printing/Printing.html